# use formail to get last email of an email file

Tags: linux, bash, email, mutt

I would like to get the last email of an email file.

I found question that splits emails:
[How to split mailbox into single file per message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281893/how-to-split-mailbox-into-single-file-per-message)

But I would like something more efficient.

Ideally, I would like to get the message id of the last email. For one email, one can simply do:

```
formail -czxMessage-ID:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
formail -s formail -czx Message-Id: <mailbox | tail -1
```

This is probably not very efficient.  However, more efficient methods are likely to be a lot more complicated.